# How to make use of alexa voice sdk or api into an application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am trying to build a Virtual Assistant using Alexa voice service and  visual studio 2017. I have installed the alexa voice service [sdk](https://github.com/alexa/avs-device-sdk) in windows and ran the SampleApp (that comes along with the library) for testing. The app is running smooth. No issues.

The sdk contains a couple of folders. Each folder is a library. For instance, ACL, ADSL, AFML, AVSCommon are folders present in the sdk etc.

ACL   - Alexa Communication Library.

ADSL  - Alexa Directive Sequence Library.

AFML  - Activity Focus Manager Library.

Each folder contains subfolders such as **include, src, test** and then CMakeLists.txt. Now the question is how do i make use of these libraries. As i need these libraries to build my application, how do i import these folders into visual studio 2017.

As I said, I compiled the sdk using cmake. Upon doing this, I got a build folder. Inside the build folder,there is a bin folder which contains each library **dlls**. Will this is be helpful. Please help me. I am completely stuck. I looked at various forums in stack overflow on how to import but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting to the right path to use the library instead of the code. As you are able to compile the code to generate a DLL file, you can now add it to your project.

In Visual Studio, right-click on your project "context menu" and use the option "AddRerefernce". Follow the prompts to add the DLL.